# Why do C# 7 ValueTuples implement the Equals method but not the double equals operator?

Tags: c#, .net, tuples, c#-7.0

Consider the following code snippet:

```
var tuple1 = (7, "foo");
var tuple2 = (7, "foo");
var tuple3 = (42, "bar");

Assert.That(tuple1.Equals(tuple2), Is.True);    //This passes
Assert.That(tuple1.Equals(tuple3), Is.False);   //This passes

Assert.That(tuple1 == tuple2, Is.True);         //This does not compile
```

The first two asserts pass. The third one does not compile.

Why does the ValueTuple implement a custom Equals method but not implement the double equals operator?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking Stack Overflow why a language/tool/framework does or does not support a feature is off-topic.

Comment: [I am asked “why doesn’t C# implement feature X?” all the time. The answer is always the same: because no one ever designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped that feature. All of them cost huge amounts of time, effort and money. Features are not cheap, and we try very hard to make sure that we are only shipping those features which give the best possible benefits to our users given our constrained time, effort and money budgets. - Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/22/why-doesnt-c-implement-top-level-methods/)

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Though I appreciate the shout-out, this is one of those rare "why not?" questions that actually makes a fair amount of sense. Someone went to all the trouble of implementing Equals, and the cost of then implementing == to simply call Equals is trivial. The way C# / .NET do equality is somewhat bizarre and error prone. In a better-designed system, there wouldn't be any difference between implementing `==`, `Equals`, `IComparable<T>`, etc, but unfortunately there is.

Comment: @EricLippert Your welcome.  I've used it many times.  Many developers don't understand the true cost of building a framework that millions if not billions of people use and the costs associated with *getting it right*. ;)

Comment: At the time I wrote this comment, it *does* (now) work: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAIAYAEqCMBuAWAChUBmbHANmwCYKB2TAb2Mze3N2tQBYKAOABQBKZq3YSAbgEMwmAJbAApgFtMAXkyCArDEwAiABZKANiYD2+4YSISpshcpV1NOvUaX7E+s5evi7TAC7XABOQX11dRAvQUVVDU1452F/W0CKcP0lAEcIaRMAZxjEOKcAOgBRPILCstUaVLSJAF9iFqA==

Comment: @JosephHumfrey you should make it an answer!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `==` operator is not implemented in the library because of conflicting requirements. For all `x` and `y` that correctly implement `object.Equals` (even if they leave it as a reference comparison), given `var tuple1 = (x, y); var tuple2 = (x, y);`, `tuple1.Equals(tuple2)` is `true`. But `tuple1 == tuple2`, if implemented, should be equivalent to `x == x && y == y`, again if implemented. The latter is *not* always true. Specifically, it's false if `x` or `y` is `double.NaN`. This is the reason why [a pull request adding an `operator ==`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/10417) to `ValueTuple` was rejected.

Implementing `==` in the compiler, where it would only work if the elements of the tuple support comparison through `==`, is [an open proposal for the C# language](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/190), but simply hasn't been implemented yet. There hasn't been much activity, there doesn't appear to be a reason right now why it wouldn't be implemented, but it simply doesn't have a high priority.

Comment: "it is inconsistent with established convention" didn't stop the Roslyn team from making the `ValueTuple` structs mutable, so that's a pretty weak argument from Neil Grafter. That aside, this is a spot on answer as it explains the "logic" behind the decision.

Comment: Thanks! The link to that pull request was exactly the explanation I was looking for and was unable to find.

Comment: Since option 2, pointwise equality, seems quite sensible but needs language support, it would make sense to delay the introduction of the tuple feature until it is implemented.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Why would that make sense? What's implemented now is done in such a way that `==` can be added later without breaking anything.

Comment: @hvd no doubt true but it seems unfortunate to me that one's conceptual model will first have to adapt to the likely unexpected absence of these operators and then subsequently adapt to their introduction at a later time. My feelings are skewed by an impression that tuples do not offer all that much value.