# How to use named tuples as optional parameters?

Tags: .net, vb.net, tuples

Here is a code sample:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim t As (t1 As String, t2 As String)
    t.t1 = "123"
    t.t2 = "456"

    TupleTest(t)
End Sub

' line below produces Constant Expression Required error for the default parameters
Sub TupleTest(Optional t As (t1 As String, t2 As String) = ("", ""))

End Sub
```

I've also tried replacing `("", "")` with `(String.Empty, String.Empty)` and `(Nothing, Nothing)`, but I get the same error.

So is it possible to have a named tuple as an optional parameter?

P.S. This is .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: Use `= Nothing`. That would be equivalent to `= default` in C# (or `= default(ValueTuple<string, string>)` in older versions of C#).

Comment: Might be missing the point here, but don't you mean _Sub TupleTest(Optional t As (t1 As String, t2 As String) = Nothing)_  ("", "") will be trying to create a tuple with empty string elements

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Yes.  I can use Nothing, but then I can't test `t` for Nothing.  `If t Is Nothing Then` doesn't compile because `Operands must be reference or nullable types`.  And `If t = Nothing` breaks because `Operator '=' is not defined for types`.  Oddly enough, this works in C# (e.g. use `default` instead of `nothing`).

Comment: @AngryHacker That's because `Is Nothing` cannot be used with a value type. Assigning `Nothing` to a value type variable, on the other hand, means creating an instance of the structure with default value. [`Nothing` is not the same as `null` in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2776902/8967612). I posted an answer below with the full example.

Comment: If you want to check for a non-provided parameter, then make it a `Nullable` i.e. `(t1 As String, t2 As String)?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Nothing` to initialize the optional parameter. That will evaluate to the default value of the structure. Then, use `.Equals` to check the equality of the argument:

```
Sub TupleTest(Optional t As (t1 As String, t2 As String) = Nothing)
    If t.Equals((Nothing, Nothing)) Then
        ' Do something
    End If

End Sub
```

Note that this is the same as with many of the existing built-in .NET structures. For example, `Point`, `Size`, `Color`, `Rectangle`, etc., but all of those have a self-referencing Shared property, which allows us to do something like this:

```
Sub Test(Optional p As Point = Nothing)
    If p = Point.Empty Then
        ' Do something
    End If
End Sub
```

ValueTuples, on the other hand, don't have an `Empty` property *and* [don't implement the equality operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42170040/8967612). That's why we have to go with the slightly awkward `.Equals((Nothing, Nothing))`.

Comment: Perfect.  `t.Equals` is what I was missing.

Comment: You don't have to do `If t.Equals((Nothing, Nothing)) Then`.  You can just do `If t.Equals(Nothing) Then`.

Comment: @AngryHacker You're right. That would work because `ValueTuple(Of String, String)` overrides the `Equals` method. However, I lean towards avoiding using `.Equals(Nothing)` with value types in general because the behavior differs depending on the implementation of `Equals` and for built-in value types, it differs between .NET versions. For example, `Point.Empty.Equals(Nothing)` would return `False` in .NET 4.6 but return `True` in .NET 6, for example because it doesn't override `Equals` in the former. I might be mistaken, but I think that used to be the case with ValueTuples too at some point.